# Why can't set a value for a row and column with the Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to set a value for a specific row and column of the spreadsheet, but I get a null pointer **before even i = 1**. I've tried changing the code but this error keeps happening and I have no more idea why.
Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

My code

```
public Workbook build(Planilha planilha) {
    File file = new File(TEMPLATE_PATH);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        Log.error(this, String.format("File %s not exists.", file.getAbsolutePath()));
        throw new NotFoundException("File not exists.");
    }

    Workbook wb = null;
    try (FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
        wb = writeMetadatas(planilha, wb);

        Map<String, Integer> header = getHeader(wb);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row;
        Cell cell;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(i);
            for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
                cell = row.getCell(j, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 0 && row.getRowNum() == 7) {
                    cell.setCellValue("teste");
                }
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.error(this, "Erro: Planilha não existe", e);
        System.err.print("Erro");
    }


    String tmpDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    File f = FileUtil.file(PATH, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".xlsx");
    try {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f);
        wb.write(fout);
        fout.flush();
        fout.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.error(this, "Erro ao abrir arquivo p escrever.");
    }
    return wb;
}
```

******NullPointer happens in `cell.setCellValue("teste");`

I'm trying to set that cell
[image]

Comment: If the `Cell` is blank, then the `Cell` might not even exist -- `row.getCell(j)` is probably returning `null`.

Comment: just that. I'll set in an empty cell. How do I?

Comment: why to get the cell from row and than row from cell? --> `cell = row.getCell(j);   if (cell.getRow().getRowNum() = ...`  -- just  `row.getRowNum()` -- than as you are checking for `row!=null` check `cell !=null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can test if the row number is a certain number outside of your `for` loop that loops over the cells in a row.  Pull that `if` outside your `j` `for` loop.

It looks like the `Cell` doesn't exist.  `row.getCell(j)` is returning `null`.

You can use a [`MissingCellPolicy`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell(int,%20org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy)) to determine whether you want to return a new `Cell` if the `Cell` doesn't already exist.  The `CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK` value will create a blank `Cell` for you if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: In addition, it also prevents the null value in row:
`for (int i = 7; i <= 10; i++) {
                row = sheet.createRow(i);
                for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
                    cell = row.getCell(j, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                    if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 0 && row.getRowNum() == 7) {
                        cell.setCellValue("teste");
                    }
                }

            }`